# Why does $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ have no extrema under the constraint of $x \le y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

To solve this question, I first tried to find the critical values using the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$. This gave me the point $(0,0)$.

Using Lagrange multipliers, I found that a possible extremum located on the border of the constraint was at $x = 0.5$. Substituting this into the equation of the constraint, I found the points $(0.5, \pm 1/\sqrt{2})$.

Substuting into the initial equation, I found:
$f(0,0) = 0$   (max)
$f(0.5, \pm 1/\sqrt{2}) = -0.5$  (min)

That's my logic, but the answer is that there are no global extrema under the constraint. I cannot find out why.

Comment: Let $x = 0$ and $y\to\pm\infty$. Then $x\leq y^2$ and $f(0,y)\to -\infty$. Hence $f$ does not have a global minimum. Now let $y = 0$ and let $x\to -\infty$. Then $x \leq y^2$ and $f(x,0) \to\infty$. Hence $f$ does not have a global maximum.

Comment: The comment above and answer below show that there are no global extrema for this function on the specified region. Note that global extrema _are_ guaranteed if the region is _closed and bounded_. This region, while closed, is not bounded because it extends infinitely in certain directions. Global extrema may still occur, but they are not guaranteed (and the comment and answer show in fact there are none).

Answer (score 1):

for all $N>0, M>0.$

$(0, N)$ and $(-M, 0)$ are acceptable values of $(x,y)$ based on the constraint.

$\lim _\limits {y\to \infty} f(0,y) = -\infty$

$\lim _\limits {x\to -\infty} f(x,0) = \infty$

$f(x,y)$ is unbounded even with the constraint.